# ASP.NET MVC - Losing JS reference of element after reload PartialView

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have this scenario: one dropdownlist of countries which reloads the "states" div content after select any country.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCountry, 
new SelectList(Model.Countries, "CountryId", "CountryName", Model.SelectedCountry))

<div id="states">
    @Html.Partial("Partial/States", Model)
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#SelectedCountry').change(function() {

            if ($(this).val() !== "-1") {

                $.get('@Url.Action("LoadStates", "Controller")', 
                $('#form').serialize(), function(result) {
                    $('#states').html(result);
                });
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Ok, it works perfectly. My problem is when I reload this PartialView, **the content lost its css styles and I can't find it on JS references**. I have this function to enable a button based on the selected dropdown values.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function canEnableButton() {
        //...
    }

    $('#SelectedCountry, #SelectedState').change(function() {
        canEnableButton();
    }
</script>
```

The first load page that `change()` jQuery function works. When I reload, this function stops work and the CSS styles dissapear.

Anyone knows what can be? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Good morning, try changing your event binding to use the jquery .on binding:

```
$('#SelectedCountry').on('change', function() {
    ...
});

$('#SelectedCountry, #SelectedState').on('change', function() {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add js and css references inside PartialView